# Create in R date, time intervals increasing by 10ms in Unix timestamp format

Tags: r, timestamp, milliseconds

I am trying to convert this vector(v) into Unix time stamps. Year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds are unimportant, but need to be introduced.

```
v = c("10ms", "20ms", "30ms", ..., "800ms")
```

**A) I thought of starting with:**

```
x <- c("2000-01-01 0:00:00.000", "2000-01-01 0:00:00.010", "2000-01-01 0:00:00.020")
y <- as.POSIXct(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "America/Chicago")
y = format(y, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS4")
```

**B) and convert that into a Unix time stamp:**

```
z = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(y,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS4", origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "America/Chicago"))
```

This yields: NA NA NA

```
z = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(y,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "America/Chicago"))
```

This yields: 946706400 946706400 946706400

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this is `R`? you should add the tag for better findability...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is surprisingly simple to fix. In your example, `z` actually *does* contain the decimal part, but it isn't printed to the console because the number is so large. If you convert it to a character, you should get the result you want:

```
as.character(round(z, 3))
#> [1] "946706400"    "946706400.01" "946706400.02"
```

Or depending on your chosen format:

```
y <- as.POSIXct("2000-01-01") + lubridate::milliseconds(1:10)
format(round(as.numeric(y), 3), digits = 13)
#>  [1] "946684800.001" "946684800.002" "946684800.003" "946684800.004" "946684800.005"
#>  [6] "946684800.006" "946684800.007" "946684800.008" "946684800.009" "946684800.010"
```

Comment: Your second solution is very useful, much better than my approch. Thank you.